# function not defined reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning reactJS and I am having issues with defining functions and calling it when button is clicked. Here is my code:

```
handleClick(){
    alert()
}

render(){

  return(
    <div><button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Here</button></div>
  )
}
```

I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: this.handleClick is not a function`

Comment: `handleClick` needs to be declared outside the `render()` function, as a property of your component.

Comment: @le_m you are right I massed when coping

Comment: @le_m with that being changed I am still getting the same error

Comment: you need to remove the `()` from `{this.handelClick()}`

Comment: Your function is called `handleClick`, but you're calling `handelClick`. Also, you should remove the parentheses in the `onClick` attribute.

Comment: @le_m what if I want to pass a value to handelClick method

Comment: @fubar yap ... my fat finger did it ... lol

Comment: made all the changes as suggested yet getting the same error

Comment: Instead of `this.handleClick`, try `handleClick`

Comment: Paste the full error message.

Comment: Paste the full code of your component.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your button `onClick` is the the button itself, not your component, therefore you get `undefined` as `handleClick` doesn't exist on button.  You need to either `bind` the click handler to `this` in you constructor:

```
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

or use arrow notation:

```
 handleClick = () => {
      console.log(' clicked!!');
  }
  render() {
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Clicky!</button>
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you are correct; without `bind()` you just won't be able to use `this` within the event handler, but that is not the issue OP is having (assuming that `handleClick()` is a method of the component class).

Comment: eh? which bit don't you think is correct?  With arrow function you will have access to this

Comment: Your answer solves a different problem - when `this` is `undefined` within the event handler. But that's not the issue OP is having.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle this would be to bind it to the constructor such that it looks like this.

```
class ComponentName extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(){
    alert('Do something')
  }

  render(){
    return(
       <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Here</button>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: now I am getting Uncaught TypeError: _this2.handleClick is not a function

Comment: @hmrous Ok, this answer is definitively correct code. You need to post your full code so we can spot your issue.